# VBA - Copy Variable Number of Rows from a Workbook to Another

Tags: vba, excel, select

Our office has recently updated to excel 2013 and a code which worked in the 2010 version is not working. I've searched on several threads here on SO and have yet to find a solution that works for this particular case.

The code identifies and copies a range of cells from an open workbook and logs them into a second workbook, one range of cells at a time. The reason it's set up to copy only 1 row at a time is because the number of rows to be copied varies from time to time. Since the change to 2013, the Selection.PasteSpecial functions have been triggering the debug prompt.

In practice, the worksheet is being used as a routing form. Once it's filled out, we run the code and save all the relevant information in a separate workbook. Since it's a routing form, the number of people on it varies, and we need a row for each person in order to track their 'status'.

The code:

```
Sub Submit()
  'Transfer code
     Dim i As Long, r As Range, coltoSearch As String

     coltoSearch = "I"

    'Change i = # to transfer rows of data. Needs to be the first row which copies over.
    'This is to identify how many rows are to be copied over. If statement ends the for loop once an "empty" cell is reached
     For i = 50 To Range(coltoSearch & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      Set r = Range(coltoSearch & i)
      If Len(r.Value) = 0 Then
       Exit For
      End If

    'Copies the next row on the loop
      Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 18)).Copy

    'open the workbook where row will be copied to
      Workbooks.Open FileName:= _
       "Workbook2"

    'definition for the first empty row in Workbook 2, or the row under the last occupied cell in the Log
      erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    'selects the first cell in the empty row
      ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select

    ' Pastes the copied row from Workbook 1 into Workbook 2. First line is highlighted when debugging
      Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
      ActiveWorkbook.Save
      ActiveWorkbook.Close
      Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'moves to the next row
    Next i
```

Any thoughts? I'm open to all options. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: The error reads: "Run-time error '1004'   PasteSpecial method of Range class failed"

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select` that's selecting only one cell but your comment reads `' Pastes the copied row...`. Anyways, avoid using `select` and create variables to hold your ranges instead.

Comment: Have you stepped through the rest of the code and confirmed that you are opening a file, that erow is assigned a number, and so forth? If pastespecial is failing, you need to make sure that everything before it is executing correctly. You should also use Option Explicit to check for errors.

Comment: @findwindow Thanks for your response. I've read that using the `select` is not ideal, but I haven't found a working alternative yet. As for the comments, I usually put them before the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Working alternative to select is

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

but just for be sure that everything is going fine you have to set the range where i you want to paste everything

```
dim rngToFill as range
Set rngToFill = ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1)
```

maybe instead of using ActiveSheet you have to define that sheet after opening the wb with

```
dim wb as Workbook, ws as worksheet
set wb = Workbooks.Open FileName:="Workbook2"
set ws = wb.Sheets(nameofthesheet) 'or number of the sheet
```

then

```
set rngToFill = ws.Cells(erow, 1)
```

then you can paste in that range using .PasteSpecial method, but before doing that, try to be sure that there is no merged cell and that the worksheet we're you are going to paste values is not protected.

```
rngToFill.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

Your code:

```
dim wb as Workbook, ws as worksheet
set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="Workbook2")
set ws = wb.Sheets(nameofthesheet) 'or number of the sheet
erow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
if erow = 0 then erow = 1
set rngToFill = ws.Cells(erow, 1)
rngToFill.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

The B plan is to use a for loop iterating throug the cell you want to copy... but it's painfull slowly!

```
    Dim wb As Workbook, newWs As Worksheet, oldWs As Worksheet
    Dim z As Integer

    Set oldWs = ActiveSheet
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Workbook2")
    Set newWs = wb.Sheets(1)
    erow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    If erow = 0 Then erow = 1

    For z = 1 To 18
        newWs.Cells(erow, z) = oldWs.Cells(i, z).Value
    Next z
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'moves to the next row
Next i
```